# Express $2\cos (n\theta)$ in terms of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

How can I show that $$2\cos(n\theta)=z^n + \frac{1}{z^n}$$

if $z=\cos\theta+i\sin \theta$

Can some one help me? thx!

Comment: what you have done?

Comment: How is the number $z$ related to $n$ and $\theta$? Without knowing that, it seems impossible to prove what you want to show. [One side of your desired equation has only $n,\theta$ and the other side only $z$]

Comment: what i know is that RHS is equal to the real part

Comment: I have tried to make the RHS to become 2cos(ntheta) but i dont know how to work on it

Comment: Still unclear, maybe (just a guess) $z=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$ and the left side is the real part of the right? It still needs to be stated just what $z$ is to denote if anyone is to help here.

Comment: oh yes , i missed the part "z=cos thea+i(sin theta)"

Comment: @GillianCheung: The proof $2\cos(n\theta)=z^n+1/z^n$ will hold  if $z, n$ & $\theta$ are related as $$z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\theta\iff z=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$$

Comment: @Boris is the only one to have written a sensible comment or answer here, given the level of the question, its appearance as homework, and the lack of work shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the Euler's formula $$z=\cos\theta+i\sin \theta$$ and from De-Moivres theorem $$\color{red}{z^n=\cos(n\theta) +i\sin(n\theta)=e^{in\theta}}\tag{1}$$ therefore $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{z^n}=(\cos (n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))^{-1}=\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)=e^{-in\theta}}\tag{2}$$ since $\cos(-n\theta)=\cos(n\theta)$ and $\sin(-n\theta)=-\sin(n\theta)$

Finally, add equations $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$\require{enclose}\cos(n\theta)+\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{i\sin(n\theta)}+\cos(n\theta)\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{-i\sin(n\theta)}=2\cos(n\theta)=\frac{1}{z^n}+{z^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $z=e^{i\theta}$, $z^n=e^{in\theta}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$.  Similarly, $z^{-n}=e^{-in\theta}=\cos(-n\theta)+i\sin(-n\theta)=\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)$ since $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

setting the value of $z=\cos\theta+i\sin \theta$, one should have  $$z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n+\frac{1}{(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n}$$
$$=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n+(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{-n}$$
using De-Moivre's theorem,
$$=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)+\cos(-n\theta)+i\sin(-n\theta)$$
$$=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)+\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)$$
$$=2\cos(n\theta)$$ or $$2\cos(n\theta)=z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$$

Comment: could someone please explain what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Nothing is wrong, some people just downvote answers for no reason I have upvoted your answer and Michaels answer also